# how to create an active image to display the level of contents in a container

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, gauge

I am not sure how to ask this as I have no idea what i am looking for is called.

Here goes. I need to graphically display the level of a container. for example: Lets say i am monitoring the contents of a glass. I just filled the glass up so its contents are at 100% so i want to display an image of the glass that is 100% filled with water, now i want the level of the water to drop in real time as the level of contents drop (in the DB).

I need a solution in c# if possible please

Any help will be highly appreciated!

(I know the question might be vague, but please help if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a framework called SignalR. This basically sends real time messages between the server and the client. (Kinda like websockets I guess, maybe SignalR is based on websockets for all I know).

So, when the value changes in the database, you could send a message to the client telling it to update it's image in some way.

You can read a little about SignalR here: http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=1210071 or you could propably check out how to use websockets.